Extending structures between objects to morphisms
Notice that many product-ish constructions are first defined on objects then morphisms between them. For example, the tensor products are first defined between vector spaces (or $R$-Modules): $V \otimes W$, and then there was tensor product of linear maps (or $R$-Modules homomorphisms) defined: $\varphi \otimes \psi$. This logic also works for direct sum, product of functions, etc. (There may be more such examples that I'm not familiar with). In other words, the constructions between objects can be naturally (in some sense) extended to morphisms? Could anybody articulate this "natural" extension more clear, and why is that possible? Thanks in advance.

Are you familiar with universal properties?

$\otimes$ extends to a bifunctor from the category of vector spaces (or whatever) to itself.

Yes, but isn't the question why there is such a bifunctor?

See for example MacLane, Categories for the Working Mathematician, chapter on adjunctions, section 7, theorem 3 (adjunctions with parameter). This should fit many examples, e.g. tensor products.

@MartinBrandenburg Yeah, I mean linear maps and vector spaces are different creatures. We defined tensor products for vector spaces by the universal property in the first place, why could we also define it for linear maps and call it the same name? Shouldn't we coin another name? And I did see somewhere else that uses another notation for tensor products of linear maps: $\varphi \odot \psi$.

@Nico Thanks! But MacLane's book seems to go too technical. I expected a more intuitive way or sort of a big picture of what's going on here.

@MarkRen I wasn't sure on which level the explanation should be, but I tried my best. Whenever we want to extend a construction, that is defined through the representation of a set valued functor, to a functor, it is always the same pattern

Okay, I will try to give you a bit of intuition. As always in category theory, the answer is the Yoneda lemma. :)
One Variable Adjunctions
Let me do a general example first to explain the pattern. Say we have a functor $F:\mathbf A\to \mathbf B$ and want a isomorphisms
\begin{align}
    \theta_{b,a} :\mathbf A(Gb,a) = \mathbf B(b,Fa)
\end{align}
where $G:\mathbf B\to \mathbf A$ is some other functor, and the isomorphisms are natural in $a$ and $b$. The Yoneda-lemma immediately gives us some information for every fixed object $b:\mathbf B$. Every transformation
\begin{align}
   \theta_{b,-}:\mathbf y(Gb) = \mathbf A(Gb,-) \to \mathbf B(b,F-)
\end{align}
is of the form $f\mapsto Gf\circ \eta_b$ for one and only one $\eta_b\in B(b,FGb)$. This is the most important step. The transformation is an isomorphism if and only if for each $a:\mathbf A$ and $g:a\to Fb$ there is a unique $f:Gb\to a$ such that $Gg\circ \eta_b = f$. This is the description of a left adjoint in terms of universal pairs $(Gb,\eta_b)$.
Say we have chosen universal pairs $(Gb,\eta_b)$ for each $b:\mathbf B$. This is the same data as a choice of natural isomorphisms $\theta_b:\mathbf y(Gb) \to \mathbf B(b,F-)$ for each fixed $b$. It does look like we have lost the information on how the left adjoint $G$ must act on arrows. But in fact, we have not, we can canonically extend $G$ back to a functor as follows. Given an arrow $f:b\to b'$, if we want that the $\theta_b$ are also natural in $b$, then the following diagram must commute.
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\mathbf y(Gb') @>{\theta_{b',-}}>> \mathbf B(b',F-)\\
@V{\mathbf y(Gf)}VV @V{\mathbf B(f,F-)}VV\\
\mathbf y(Gb) @>{\theta_{b,-}}>> \mathbf B(b,F-)
\end{CD}
But because $\theta_b$ and $\theta_{b'}$ are invertible we immediatelly see that $\mathbf y(Gf) = \theta_{b}^{-1}\circ \mathbf B(f,F-)\circ \theta_{b'}$. And since the contravariant Yoneda embedding $\mathbf y$ is fully faithful, we can also determine $Gf$. The morphism $Gf: Gb\to Gb'$ must be the unique morphism such that $\mathbf y(Gf)$ is the transformation described above. Chasing $id_{Gb'}$ both ways around the diagram gives us the following equation.
\begin{align}
\eta_{b'} \circ f = FGf\circ \eta_b
\end{align}
This shows us more directly how $Gf$ is defined in terms of the universal property of the pair $(Gb,\eta_b)$.
Tensor Products:
This was a one variable adjunction, but the same kind of argument can be applied to many variable adjunctions. Or in fact any other kind of construction that is defined through the representation of some functor. To show this I will do your example, namely tensor products of $R$-modules. What we want is a natural isomorphism
\begin{align}
\theta_{M,N,L}: Mod_R(M\otimes_RN,L) = Bilin_R(M,N;L)
\end{align}
As in the case of 1-variable adjunctions discussed above we immediatelly see that the left functor is of the form $\mathbf y(M\otimes_R N)$ once we fix $M$ and $N$. The Yoneda lemma tells us that the transormations $\theta_{M,N,-}$ contain exactly the same information as universal pairs $(M\otimes_RN, \otimes)$, where $\otimes:M\times N\to M\otimes_RN$ is the special $R$-bilinear map with the universal property as it is usually described in algebra. As before it seems like we have lost the information on how $\theta_R$ acts on morphism, but we haven't in fact. Given $f:M\to M'$ and $g: N\to N'$ we know that $f\otimes_R g$ must be such that the following diagram commutes.
\begin{CD}
\mathbf y(M'\otimes_R N') @>{\theta_{M',N',-}}>> Bilin(M',N';-)\\
@V{\mathbf y(f\otimes_R g)}VV @V{Bilin_R(f,g;-)}VV\\
\mathbf y(M\otimes_R N) @>{\theta_{M,N,-}}>> Bilin(M,N;-)
\end{CD}
As before there is only one such map $f\otimes_Rg$ for which this is the case. Chasing $id_{M'\otimes N'}$ both ways around the diagram will give you a more explicit description of $f\otimes_R g$.
